# will this output a random shuffle a million times? rand() c++

Tags: random, shuffle

i'm attempting to run a million simulations of a card game to return a percentage "casino house edge."

my understanding of the rand() function is not clear enough to know whether this will generate a new shuffle every time or if it has a limit. in other words, at some point into the million games, will the same patterns of shuffles emerge?

```
  srand(time(NULL));

for (int games=0;games<iGames;games++){

                  ///shuffle///
for (int i=0; i<(iUserDeckSize-1); i++) {
    int r = i + (rand() % (iUserDeckSize-i)); // Random remaining position.
    card temp = cards[i]; cards[i] = cards[r]; cards[r] = temp;
}

// rest of card game code goes here
}
```

Comment: There should be a shuffle in `<algorithm>` if my memory is right... Here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/

Comment: `rand()` is a pseudo-random number generator. This means that *eventually* (and likely a very-large-don't-care-about eventually) there will be a repeating sequence. However, since this restart may happen "not always at the start of a shuffle" then it seems like there could be *more* shuffle permutations than the cycle length of the employed PRNG.

Comment: I believe it's implementation specific, see here for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026327/what-common-algorithms-are-used-for-cs-rand. But I'd be astounded if practical implementations began repeating that quickly, I would have thought at least you'd get into the billions allowed by an int32.

Comment: @PeterJ: That would make a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No for 2 reasons (one you thought about and one not-so-obvious).

The algorithm you are using is wrong. Setting aside worrisome -1 (the last element will not be shuffled at all) you have `n^n` possible runs (space of received random numbers) while there is `n!` possible shuffles. In general `n!` is not a factor of `n^n` hence you have biased output (i.e. some outcomes will occur more often then others). I would recommend either implement the [Knuth-Tares shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle) or use already implemented algorithm like `random_shuffle` from `<algorithm>`.

That said - you need to have the PRNG which have at least `n!` states. Depending on the deck size rand() may not be enough - it typically have ~48 bits while standard 52-card deck have ~225 bits of state (`log2(52!)`) - in other words there is no chance of hitting some sequences (it might not be a problem but overhead of better PRNG is negligible). I would look on [boost random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) as it have several good PRNG implementations and at least one would probably be sufficiently good (say [mt11213b](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost/random/mt11213b.html) for 52-card example).

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's implementation specific, see here for instance [What common algorithms are used for C's rand()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026327/what-common-algorithms-are-used-for-cs-rand).  But I'd be astounded if practical implementations began repeating that quickly, I would have thought you'd at least get into the billions allowed by an int32.