# Implement glibc random number generator in Windows

Tags: windows, embedded, glibc, prng

I have an embedded device using the standard glibc `srand()`/`rand()` functions to generate pseudo-random values. For the same seed `x` I need to get the same values for `rand()` on a Windows machine. To my surpise however, this isn't as simple as it seems.

Glibc apparently used two algorithms for it's random number generator. An older one, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026327/what-common-algorithms-are-used-for-cs-rand), and a [newer one](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/random_r.c;h=87cfdc285c0f6e4a4911eac0f6dd5efa2c3fb8b6;hb=HEAD), which my embedded device uses. How can I implement the latter on another platform? My knowlegde of C isn't thorough enough to understand what exactly is happening there.

Comment: Why not try to compile it on Windows and work through the errors?  You might get better/easier results if you use a MinGW compiler.  Of course there might also be licensing issues, if your Windows application can't be GPL licensed.

Comment: In the end, this was the way to go (and therefore the answer of my question).