# Random() efficiency in C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, performance, random

I am writing function where I need to find the random number between 1 - 10. One of the easiest way is to use random() libc call. I am going to use this function a lot. But I don't know how efficient it will be. If any one has idea about efficiency of random() that will be a help ?

Also I notice that random() give the same pattern in 2 runs.

```
int main()
{
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
    cout << random() % 10 << endl;     
   }
}
```

Output 1st time :- 3 6 7 5 3 5 6 2 9 1

Second time also I got same output.

Then how come it's random ?

Comment: Use a profiler if you're worried about performace. If you run the randomizer with the same seed, it will always give the same output.

Comment: Actually I used Linux perf but there it's is not showing anything (like where it's consuming time). It's just showing how much CPU cycle it consume and it was around 1.73% of total CPU.

Comment: "efficiency" as in "performance" or "efficiency" as in "how good are the random numbers"? The latter is clearly a case of "you need to use srand()" [or similar] to start the random number sequence at a different point. "Good" random numbers is not trivial, so you may need further work if you need truly good random numbers [e.g. games where predictability becomes an issue, or using the numbers for scientific purposes where the distribution is important]

Comment: Any reason for negative marking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Others have explained why it's the same sequence every time, but this is how you generate a random number with *C++*:

```
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::random_device rd{}; //(hopefully) truly random device
    std::mt19937 engine{rd()}; //seed a pseudo rng with random_device
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d(1,10); //1 to 10, inclusive
    int RandNum = d(engine); //generate
    return 0;
}
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Answer (score 2):

The actual execution time depends on your platform of course, but it is pretty much straight forward, couple multiplication and divisions or shifts:

[What common algorithms are used for C's rand()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026327/what-common-algorithms-are-used-for-cs-rand)

I don't think you should be worried. If you need a lot of random numbers, then another random source probably would be a better choice for you.

If you are looking for tweaks, how about splitting the result from rand() into individual digits to get several results per call.

Comment: The idea of splitting the result from `rand()` into individual digits (say, blocks of 4 bits to get random numbers from 1-10, say, by ignoring 0000, 1111, 1110, 1101, 1100 and 1011) is an interesting one but it would be important to [test the quality of the random numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestU01) generated this way because the lower bits in most pseudo-random numbers are typically less random than the higher-valued bits.

Answer (score 0):

This way is very simple and effective, you only need to set the seed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        cout << rand() % 10 << endl;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem of getting same pattern in 2 runs just add the function        randomize()