# Does C always generate the same random sequence?

Tags: c, random

I ran a program that called `rand()` four times. I used the modulus operator to limit the range to 1–6. The integers produced were 2, 5, 4, and 2. I reran the program and got the same numbers. Then I created a brand new program that also called `rand()` four times, and I still got the integer sequence 2, 5, 4, 2. Then I shut the computer down, powered back up, created another new program that called `rand()` four times, and still got the sequence 2, 5, 4, 2.

I understand the basics that you need to “seed” the RNG using `srand()`, which starts the sequence at different points, but I'm just curious: forgetting about seeding for a moment, is the sequence generated by `rand()` installation, compiler, and/or OS dependent? For example, would any of the following result in a different sequence:

- uninstalling and reinstalling the C compiler on my computer

  installing and using a different C compiler on my computer

  running the program on someone else's computer with the same compiler?

  running the program on someone else's computer with a different compiler (and perhaps a different OS)?

Or is it just a matter of all C compilers using the same RNG algorithm and so the pseudorandom sequence (starting from the beginning) will be the same for everyone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What common algorithms are used for C's rand()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026327/what-common-algorithms-are-used-for-cs-rand)

Comment: Why not just consult the [C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.2.1)

Comment: @Olaf because my question is not specifically and directly addressed by the spec, making the answer hard to infer -- particularly for a beginner. And also because there are at least some kind people on this site who are understanding with beginners and willing to help.

Comment: It is **exactly answered** by the link to the **standard** I posted. Just read on to `srand` about repeatability. As for generating the same sequence: does the standard enforce a particular algorithm?. Note that the link is not just a specification, but the internation standard (well, the final draft, but there is no significant difference; the standard is pay-crap).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't call `srand`, C says:

> C99, 7.20.2.2p2) "If rand is called before any calls to srand have been made, the same sequence shall be generated as when srand is first called with a seed value of 1."

So if your `rand` function (which is unspecified in the C Standard and let to the implementation) is an algorithmtic PRNG, it is very likely you get the same sequence again and again if you don't call `srand`.

Comment: But that does not answer the question where the "2, 5, 4, 2" sequence comes from. (Why exactly 2, 5, 4, 2?)

Comment: @idmean I think we don't have the same understanding of his question

Comment: @ouah So if rand() is unspecified and left to the implementation, can you speculate what this says about what would be generated by different compilers, different machines, different OSs, etc.

Comment: The 2, 5, 4, 2 sequence comes from the particular rand() algorithm in use with a seed of 1 modified by whatever algorithm is being used to limit the values to 1, 6.  For that particular compiler/version the sequence will always be the same for a seed of 1.  For a different compiler/version there might be a different algorithm or starting value being used so the sequence might be completely different.

Comment: @yroc there are many implementations of `rand` so you cannot rely that different systems, different libc or different libc versions implement the same algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "ran the program four times", it sounds like you're only getting one value of `rand()` for each seed, which will not be a random sequence. To get a random sequence you need to call `srand()` once and `rand()` multiple times *in the same program run*. If you need a random sequence across executions of a program, you'll have to use something like `/dev/random`.

Comment: I didn't say I ran the program four times. I said I ran a program that called rand() four times.

Comment: Yeah, English is kind of ambiguous there. In that case, it's probably the value you're using in `srand()`.

Answer (score 0):

> forgetting about seeding for a moment, is the sequence generated by rand() installation, compiler, and/or OS dependent?

It depends on the particular library implementation, which may be part of the compiler installation or installed separately.  A different library implementation *may* give a different sequence.  I would expect the same library implementation on two different systems to give the same sequence of values, but that's assuming it doesn't use local system information as part the PRNG algorithm.

The only requirement is that the sequence always be the same for the same seed value, and that if `rand` is called without a preceding call to `srand` that it behave as though `srand` had been called with a seed of `1`.